# How to make common code for interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

IDE: VS 2010, C# .net

I have a Child class A and B which is implementing Interface I which contains some properties.

See this code

```
class A : UserControl, I
{
    string _str = "From a";
    string str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set { _str = value; }
    }
}

class B : UserControl, I
{

    string _str = "From b";
    string str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set { _str = value; }
    }
}
```

Here we can see the code

```
string str
{
    get { return _str; }
    set { _str = value; }
}
```

This code is common in both classes A and B, So Is there any way to keep this code common..?

Note: Both A and B are user controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, create an abstract class `C` that both `A` and `B` derive from.

Alternatively, if you want *all* implementations of your interface to have a default non-overridable method, you could use an extension method.

The scenario you showed us, however, would be best implemented by means of a constructor.

```
class A : C
{
    public A() : base("From a")
    {

    }
}

abstract class C : I, UserControl
{
    public string Str {get; set;}  

    protected C(string someStr)
    {
        Str = someStr;
    }
}
```